# mouse coordinates to isometric coordinates

Tags: javascript, coordinates, isometric

I'm trying to get the right tile in the isometric world by mouse position.

I've read some theads about this, but it doesn't seem to work for me. 
The basic Idea is to recalculate the normal mouse coordinates to the isometric tile-coordinates. [image: Isometric Map]

As you can see the mouse cursor is at the tile 5/4 and the recalculation is wrong (the tile selected is 4/5). This is my Code:

```
var params.tx = 100, params.ty=54,
PI = 3.14152,
x1 = x_mouse - params.tx*5,
y1 = y_mouse * -2,
xr = Math.cos(PI/4)*x1 - Math.sin(PI/4)*y1,
yr = Math.sin(PI/4)*x1 + Math.cos(PI/4)*y1,
diag = (params.ty) * Math.sqrt(2),
x2 = parseInt(xr / diag)+1, 
y2 = parseInt(yr * -1 / diag)+1;
```

The original height of a tile is 54px, but as you can see, only the border tiles show their full height. The rest of the tiles are cut by 4 pixels.

Please help me - may be my whole formula is wrong.